# In Mortal Engines, why are there no "protector" cities?

Tags: mortal-engines

**Edit:** As I'm reasonably certain there are no protector cities I'm rewording the question to ask whether there is a specific in-universe reason this strategy has not been pursued.

At the start of the Mortal Engines movie we see London chasing and eating Salthook, a small salt-mining town. Afterwards we know from dialogue that they have obtained enough fuel to last them a week, as well as some items such as an electric toaster. But they didn't get any salt (because Salthook dumped it during the chase) and they probably can't obtain it so easily in the future, because they just ate the town that specialised in producing it.

Suppose that instead of preying on towns like Salthook, London offered them protection from predators in return for payment in kind (Salthook after all was a trading town). Smaller settlements would be eager to align themselves with a protector and London would obtain resources they couldn't easily produce themselves, on a more sustainable basis than they would through predation.

This would seem like a viable solution to the problem of London and other big traction cities at the time the novels and movie are set: too many predators chasing ever smaller and fewer prey. It could be seen as a sort of "evolution", from municipal hunter-gathering to municipal "agriculture". So I'm wondering if there is a  reason this strategy hasn't been tried?

Comment: It's **Municipal Darwinism**.

Comment: @Rand yes I know, but I needed some terms for my speculations about what behaviours could evolve among mobile cities, so I made some up :-)

Comment: Oh, I'm not criticising your terminology :-) But the point of Darwinism is it's a dog-eat-dog world, everyone competing and the best surviving. Cooperation doesn't really feature.

Comment: That's fair enough as a plot element, but co-operation often does emerge in a Darwinian context. Wolves hunt in packs, pilot fish help sharks and in return get some protection, small hairless ape-like creatures turn out to be quite powerful collectively even though all the individuals are comparatively weak, ...

Comment: That would make a different story than what the author wanted to tell.

Comment: What you're describing is "protection" in the mafia sense.

Comment: @Valorum what I'm envisaging is more like Renaissance-era civilization: the local prince has an interest in protecting the local merchants and traders because if they prosper more will come to him and his city-state will flourish - more so than if he simply extorts tribute from them.

Comment: That said, they are still paying for security - a situation which always has the potential to turn into a protection racket if it is not already.
There are those who say the same about modern states. If you don't pay your taxes it will most likely be agents of the local "prince" who show up at your door demanding their "fee", not raiders from a neighboring state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

London is relatively unique in the story given how far it is from its *natural* hunting grounds. By comparison, German-speaking cities are far more happy to ally and offer mutual protection. This evidently includes allowing smaller 'trading towns' to group around them.

> And so the *Traktionstadtsgesellschaft* was born. The twelve great
>   cities, swiftly joined by others, swore that they would eat no mobile
>   town until the Green Storm was destroyed. They would survive instead
>   by devouring Mossie ships and forts and static settlements until they
>   had made the world safe again for Municipal Darwinism, which every
>   civilized person knew was the most natural, sensible and fair way of
>   life ever devised.
>
> They turned, they fought, and they forced the startled Green Storm to
>   a stalemate. Now, a broad ribbon of no-man’s-land wriggled across the
>   Hunting Ground from the southern fringes of the Rustwater Marshes to
>   the edges of the Ice Wastes, marking the boundary between two worlds.
>   To the east of it the Green Storm were struggling to plant new static
>   settlements and reclaim for their farmers land which had been ploughed
>   up and polluted by centuries of Municipal Darwinism. To the west, life
>   went on almost as before, with cities hunting towns and towns hunting
>   villages; the only difference was that most mayors sent a portion of
>   their catch to feed the Traktionstadts.

That being said, they recognise that once the immediate threat of the Green Storm is passed, they can return to Municipal Darwinism which is considered to be ***the appropriate and preferable state of being.***

---

You might also want to note that the idea of satellite towns has been tried before, but in the latter days of the traction era everything has become increasingly centralised. Towns do trade with London though, presumably this offers them some limited protection.

> Whatever the town was, it was small, only a suburb really. Tom amused
>   himself by trying to work out what it might be while Hester picked the
>   lock on a hatchway and led him up a long stairwell with rusty walls
>   that steamed in the heat from the engines. **He thought it looked a bit
>   like Crawley, or Purley Spokes, the suburbs that London had built back
>   in the great old days when there was so much prey that cities could
>   afford to build little satellite towns. If so, it might have its own
>   merchant airships, licensed to trade with London.**

Comment: Thanks. I see that alliances and co-operation do exist, but an important plot element is that large numbers of people accept as natural a lifestyle which to us is thoroughly unnatural and will obviously have to come to an end sooner or later.